# How to properly sidescroll a screen in android, using canvas?

Tags: android, animation, canvas, scroll

Ok, I am developing a sidescrolling game and my problem is on how to properly draw and update the screen. I am drawing on a SurfaceView and I use Path to make the contourns, currently the algorithm only draws this:

And I am sidescrolling by using Path.offSet() and then canvas.drawPath(), later on I update the last X position on the path by using Path.addRect() (and thats basically how I am drawing everything: using Path.addRect())

So here is the thread that updates the screen:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int x = LibraryLoader.getTerrainSizeX();
    int y = LibraryLoader.getTerrainSizeY();

    int count = 0;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Path path = new Path();
    makePath(path, x, y, 0, LibraryLoader.getTerrainThickness());
    Path path2 = new Path();
    makePath(path2, x, y, LibraryLoader.getTerrainThickness(), y);
 while (run) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                fps = fps();
                drawMyData(c, path, path2, paint, fps);
                LibraryLoader.updateOffSet();
                updatePaths(path, path2, x, y);
                if ((count++) == (x / 2) - 1) {
                    LibraryLoader.updateOffSetArray();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        } finally {
            if (c != null) {surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);}
        }
    }
```

and its respective methods:

```
public void updatePaths(Path path, Path path2, int x, int y) {
    path.offset(-1f, 0);
    path.addRect(x-3, topValue, x-2, bottomValue, Path.Direction.CW);
    path2.offset(-1f, 0);
    path2.addRect(x-3, topValue, x-2, y, Path.Direction.CW);
}
```

So, in my phone it works perfectly at 60fps, the problem is I tested in a lower end device and it begins at 40fps then drops every update until it gets below 10fps...(and keeps dropping). I guess I need to clean the state of the path, or I shouldn't even be using the Path class to begin with. So my question is how should I update the screen with the best performance? Obs: The canvas is not hardware accelerated.

Comment: Recommend watching these old Google IO videos: https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic and https://youtu.be/7-62tRHLcHk

Comment: Yes, thanks man! (guess you are in a rush ;D)...I am aware this is a very basic question...I guess I'm gonna prepare my snack to watch these...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well folks I figured out that I was wrong about everything I did. The answer is simple: If your android application updates the whole screen every frame, use Opengl. Canvas is for app design for what I've seen, hope I am not mistaken. For example, if you want to make a custom animation for a LOGO or a button, so you use canvas, I guess. If anyone stumbles in this post do watch the videos Morrison Chang mentioned, they are very helpful to put you on the right track. Cheers.